# Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, h2

```
    spring:
  application:
    name: businessassistant-opendata
  jmx:
    enabled: true
h2:
       console:
       enabled: true
       path: /h2-console
    
datasource:
      url: jdbc:h2:file:~/test
      driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
      username: sa
      password:
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

server:
  port: 8762
```

Hi. I try to launch my Gradle project, but I have problem configuration with my properties. I try to understand what happens but I don't find the solution.  Thanks for your time.

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.6.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure', version: '2.6.1'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20210307'
    implementation group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version: '2.6.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.3.13'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '5.3.13'

    // JAX-B dependencies for JDK 9+
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2'
    

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
    testImplementation group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: '3.6.1'
    testImplementation group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest', version: '2.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '4.1.0'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '5.3.13'
    implementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '2.0.202'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.6.1'
```

Thaqt is the build.gradle file.

Comment: Maybe add your build.gradle file (before you applied my solution) so others can understand your problem better.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the driver of h2 to your dependencies:

build.gradle:

```
//...

dependencies {
  //...
  implementation 'com.h2database:h2:2.0.202'
}
```

Comment: Hola. Ya estaban añadidas.

Comment: you can upvote the answer if you find it correct.